# IIS Edge browser address-bar showing "about:blank" not "Loading" and focus is retained in the address-bar

Tags: vb.net, webforms, visual-studio-2019, microsoft-edge

I had updated VS-2019 a few times. After one update my locally running Web-Forms application (being developed with VS-2019) no longer starts the MS-Edge browser showing "Loading" in the address-bar as was previously.

Now the address bar shows "about-blank" until the page gets loaded and then shows "https://localhost:22222/Login01" (as expected). However the FOCUS remains on this text in the Edge address-bar.

From VS-2019 -key to start and debug my application, I do not know why (1) "about:blank" is displayed and (2) why focus remains in Edge address-bar.

This prevents the FOCUS NOT being placed on the Login-Control "Username" textbox as the current code directs.

I welcome your advice, comments and contribution to this question.
Thanks. John

Information:
**MS-Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.11.2**

**MS-Edge Version 93.0.961.38 (Official build) (64-bit)**

Code:

```
Private Sub Login01_PreRender(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRender

If (Not IsPostBack) Then
    ' Prepare initial focus.
    Dim oCtrlUserName As TextBox = CType(Login1.FindControl("UserName"), TextBox)
    SetFocus(oCtrlUserName.ClientID)
End If  End Sub
```

Comment: You should probably add the versions of VS and Edge, and add the code that sets the cursor.

Comment: Private Sub Login01_PreRender(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRender
      If (Not IsPostBack) Then
   ' Prepare initial focus.
   Dim oCtrlUserName As TextBox = CType(Login1.FindControl("UserName"), TextBox)
   SetFocus(oCtrlUserName.ClientID)
      End If
   End Sub

Comment: MS-Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.11.2
MS-Edge Version 93.0.961.38 (Official build) (64-bit)

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Comment: Yes...Xudong Peng... your answer is selected as THE ANSWER. Thank you very much.  You are BRILLIANT for finding this as the solution.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a simple demo and reproduced the same issue you mentioned, but the environment is a little different, using Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.8.5. I found that the cause of the problem was that I enabled script debugging. If this function is disabled, it will work correctly.

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Xudong Peng.  Your solution fixed this question.  Thank you very much.  You are BRILLIANT!!! for even knowing this could solve the problem. Thanks.